# how display grids using table

Tags: html, angularjs

Am using grid to diplay data from my data base. I would display grids in a table of 3 columns inthis way : 
[image]

I try this code

```
 <table style="width:70%" ng-repeat="e in events"  >
 <tr>
 <td>
      <div class="col-md-3 ticket-grid"   >
        <div class="tickets">
          <div class="grid-right">
            <font color="red"><h3>{{e.name}}</h3></font>
             Location: {{e.loc}}<br>
             Category: Sport   <br>
             Start date: <br>
             End date:
             Description: <span>{{e.description}}</span> <br>
             Contact:  {{e.contact}}<br>
             <a href="#" class="hvr-icon-fade">Confirm</a>
             <a href="#" class="hvr-icon-sink-away">Refuse</a>
          </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
       </div>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 </tr>
</table>
```

PS: events is an array that contains my data.
But i get this  result

[image]

Any help please

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `ng-repeat` to the element you want repeated. In your version you are creating new `<table>` with all contents for each record in *events*. Moving it to the `<td>` will leave you with same issue as it will just create a new row for each record.

If you are using bootstrap - you should just use the [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) instead of the `<table>` for layouts, something like.

```
<div ng-repeat="e in events">
   <div class="col-md-4 ticket-grid" >
        <div class="tickets">
          <div class="grid-right">
            <font color="red"><h3>{{e.name}}</h3></font>
             Location: {{e.loc}}<br>
             Category: Sport   <br>
             Start date: <br>
             End date:
             Description: <span>{{e.description}}</span> <br>
             Contact:  {{e.contact}}<br>
             <a href="#" class="hvr-icon-fade">Confirm</a>
             <a href="#" class="hvr-icon-sink-away">Refuse</a>
          </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

You will need something like, to break out of the `ng-repeat` loop every 3 records:

```
 <div class="clearfix" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0"></div>
```

See Plunker examples for more of an idea [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/mDBqDNYkgRDEI25ty01G?p=preview)